# is there a difference between "slide" and "slip"

Tags: word-meaning

Is there any difference between the words "slide" and "slip" I search for the difference a lot of time but I didn't find it

Comment: A slide is an apparatus in a kids' playpark; a slip is an item of women's underwear.

Comment: What did you find?

Comment: On the other hand, a landslip and a landslide are the same thing. You need to provide more context.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As verbs, 'slide' is a general verb for the action of moving smoothly along a surface; 'slip' is used when the sliding is accidental or not desired and for a short distance.

> slide
>
> move smoothly along a surface while maintaining continuous contact
> with it.
>
> slip
>
> an act of sliding unintentionally for a short distance.
>
> (Oxford Languages)

Comment: And a slip may lead to a slide.  When I walked up Glastonbury Tor in rain, I almost had occasion to say: “I slipped on the wet grass and slid down the slope.”

Comment: In addition to what @MichaelHarvey wrote, sliding always involves contact with a surface. A door **slides along** a track. A suitcase **slides down** a ramp. Slipping does not necessarily involve any such surface contact. An envelope may be **slipped through** a mail slot.